# Heapsort Algorithm Incorrect Output

Tags: vb.net, binary-tree, heapsort

First off, my apologies for asking a rather limited question. I understand the answer may not necessarily be beneficial to others, but I've been trying to figure out the issue to no avail.

When running the code, no error is present but the output matches the input. The purpose of the algorithm is to output the sorted array.

Code:

```
Dim heap() As Integer = {4, 9, 2, 1, 6, 3, 5, 7}
Dim sortedArray() As Integer
Dim listLength As Integer = heap.Length
Dim iteration As Integer
Dim max As Integer

Sub Main()

    Console.Write("Unsorted list: ")

    For i = 0 To 7
        Console.Write(heap(i))
        Console.Write(" ")
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf)

    HeapSort(heap)


    Console.Write("Sorted list: ")
    For i = 0 To 7
        Console.Write(heap(i))
        Console.Write(" ")
    Next

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

Sub HeapSort(ByRef heap() As Integer)
    Dim temp As Integer
    createheap(heap)
    For i = listLength To 1
        iteration = i
        temp = heap(iteration)
        heap(iteration) = heap(1)
        heap(1) = temp
        listLength = listLength - 1
        heapify(iteration, heap)
    Next

End Sub

Sub createheap(ByRef heap() As Integer)
    For i = listLength / 2 To 1
        iteration = i
        heapify(iteration, heap)
    Next
End Sub

Sub heapify(iteration As Integer, heap() As Integer)
    max = iteration
    Dim left As Integer = 2 * iteration
    Dim right As Integer = 2 * iteration + 1
    Dim temp As Integer

    If left <= listLength And heap(left) > heap(max) Then
        max = left
    Else
        max = iteration
    End If

    If right <= listlength And heap(right) > heap(max) Then
        max = right
    End If

    If max = Not iteration Then
        temp = heap(iteration)
        heap(iteration) = heap(max)
        heap(max) = temp

        heapify(max, heap)

    End If
End Sub
```

The output is: 4 9 2 1 6 3 5 7

Where can the issue(s) be located? Many thanks in advance and allow me to apologise again for what could be considered an inappropriate question.

Comment: Have you debugged your code?  Read [ask] and taking the [tour] if you want to learn how SO works

Comment: Do you know how the Heapsort algorithm works, right now your code isn't close. It involves preparing the list by first turning it into a max heap. The algorithm then repeatedly swaps the first value of the list with the last value, decreasing the range of values considered in the heap operation by one, and then sifting the new first value into its position in the heap. This will repeat until the range of considered values is one value in length.

Comment: The loops are all wrong too which is something you will instantly discover using the Debugger.  `For i = listLength To 1` is never going to execute

Comment: @Plutonix I noticed that as well, but until the OP understands the algorithm he won't understand and for obvious reasons I didn't need to comment on other issues... Good catch.

Comment: I agree.  They also need to understand that Debugging is an integral, nay essential skill in writing software.  Hoping that maybe they at least learn how to set a breakpoint before Someone comes along and rewrites it for them.

Comment: @Plutonix I concur fully.

Comment: @R  What we are saying is that there are lots of problems starting with the algorithm and then the code.  My point was that neither Mr Z nor I ran your code.  We compiled it in our heads to make note of different things: that ability only comes after years and years of debugging code.  The result is that those kinds of mistakes are (a little) less likely in code we write.  Debugging is a skill you must learn.

Comment: I wholly appreciate the point you are making. My concern however is that unless given at least a general direction, I'm likely to make very little progress to fixing the issue. Rest assured I did not come here expecting someone to completely rewrite my code, simply give me an idea of where the issue lies and a suggestion on how I may go about fixing it. I mean this with no disrespect, but simply stating that the reason I'm in this position is because I failed to perform what can rightfully be considered a core skill does not provide me with any direction for this particular problem.